# Android File Transfer cannot connect to device from Mac

Tags: file-transfer

Trying to find a way to transfer a video file onto my new S7 Edge from my Mac and it seemed like Android File Transfer was the only way to do it, but no matter what I do, I can't get past an error message saying "Could not connect to device. Try reconnecting or restarting your device."

I've restarted my phone and my computer, used different USB ports, uninstalled and reinstalled the program itself, and still no luck :( I've heard that the Samsung program Kies can cause problems, but I've never installed it. Help?

Running OS 10.12.1

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper :(
It's a new phone and a fairly new computer. There's got to be something I'm missing. sigh

Answer (score 0):

My MAC is running MacOS 10.12.2, and my phone is an S7 Edge running the UK release Nougat 7.0. With Android File Transfer (AFT) I was also getting the error "Could not connect to device. Try reconnecting or restarting your device.", until I uninstalled Kies on the MAC. Thereafter AFT connected to the device and I was able to transfer files from the phone simply by dragging them to a(ny) folder on the MAC.

I have USB debugging enabled, MTP mode selected in phone's settings, and I had to respond "Allow" to a pop-up on the phone.